# HTML5 Canvas slows down with each stroke and clear

Tags: html, canvas

I've been playing around with the HTML5 Canvas and I've noticed something that I couldn't find a resolution for online. Here's the simple code I'm playing with

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <br />
    <button id="draw">draw</button>
    <button id="clear">clear</button>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        $("#draw").bind("click", function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                context.moveTo(0, i);
                context.lineTo(100, 100);
                context.stroke();
            }
        });
        $("#clear").bind("click", function () {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        });
    } ());
</script>
```

Each time that I press draw, the speed at which it completes seems to slow down exponentially. Could anyone know why this is happening?

It slows down the most through IE. Chrome seems to complete it faster with each draw click, but you can still definitely notice a speed reduction.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `<canvas>` element keeps track of a current path (i.e., set of points, lines, and curves). `canvas.moveTo`, `canvas.lineTo`, and `canvas.stroke` all operate on the current path. Every time you call `canvas.moveTo` or `canvas.lineTo` you are adding to the current path. As the path gets more and more complex, drawing gets slower and slower.

You can clear the path by calling `canvas.beginPath()`. Doing this at the start of your draw function should get rid of the slowdown.

Comment: Perfect!! Worked like a charm for me also :)

Comment: Also, you can move the context.stroke(); function outside of the for loop for an even better optimization. Build the paths then stroke them all at once, instead of multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for this! On the W3Schools documentation for canvas, it didn't really specify the importance of closing off your path's, but I was literally killing the browser in a game I'm making after 30 seconds.