# Optimize moving pattern on canvas?

Tags: canvas, three.js

I'm trying to achieve moving a pattern inside a canvas, but after some seconds (or minutes) the situation becomes unmanageable.

```
canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 240;
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
image = new Image();
image.src = 'pattern.png';
t = 0;

update();

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.save();

  ctx.translate(t, 2*t);
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat');
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();

  t++;

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rzn0ds4/) (memory consumption alert).

My goal is to use that canvas as a texture for a THREEjs sprite, running continuously in the scene. I cannot animate the sprite material playing with uvOffsets, since there will be 3 or 4 transparent patterns moving in different directions and overlapping each other. Is it possibile to tweak it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's your specific question? "tweak" could mean anything. Also, would it not be better to write your own shader rather than sending a canvas to a material?

Comment: My question is to know if there's a better way to achieve that result. With this method, the CPU usage becames very high After few minutes (100% CPU in Safari, on the lastest MacBook Pro).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas slows down with each stroke and clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558895/html5-canvas-slows-down-with-each-stroke-and-clear)

Comment: I would definitely be creating my own ShaderMaterial in this case, the performance would be quite a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it slows down over time is because `rect()` will add and accumulate on the path object over time so each time `fill()` is called all those rectangle paths are filled.

Simply replace this line:

```
ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

with

```
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Optionally add a `beginPath()` before adding the `rect()`. `fillRect()` rasterizes directly without adding the rectangle to the path.

Also remember to compensate the rectangle position as the area it fills will also move, eventually to outside the canvas area. Simply compensate by using the reverse of the translation values:

```
ctx.fillRect(-t, -t*2, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

In newer browsers we can use `setTransform` directly on the `CanvasPattern` object:

```
// assuming pattern is set as fill-style
ctx.fillStyle.setTransform(1,0,0,1, x, y);
```

**A modified example incl. some other suggestions to optimize the loop:**

```
...
image.onload = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat');
  update();
};

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, t, 2*t);  // optionally replace save/restore/translate
  ctx.fillRect(-t, -t*2, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  t++;

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In this way the pattern [moves down](https://jsfiddle.net/qdmc9fat/), without recreating repeated content on left and top. I also tried with `beginPath()`, but the result is the same. Is it possible to have the same behavior of my jsfiddle?

Comment: @xAlien95 do you mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/qdmc9fat/1/)? Since the canvas is translated the area for fillRect is moved. Just compensate by drawing the rect equal amount in the opposite direction.

Comment: @xAlien95 excellent! I updated the answer to take this into consideration. Also check out the setTransform on the pattern object itself.

Comment: @Damsorian only if you want to remove remains from the previous render (due to f.ex. spill or transparency).