# HTML5 Canvas and JS Framerate slowly drops to 0

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to setup an html 5 canvas for a game and my fps starts out fine but then it slowly falls to 0 fps and lags the browser window out. I feel like I am missing something very important.

JS I am using to manage the refresh and drawing:

```
var stop = false;
var frameCount = 0;
var $results = $("#stats");
var fps, fpsInterval, startTime, now, then, elapsed;

var $canvas = $("#gameWorld")[0];
var context = $canvas.getContext("2d");

startAnimating(30);

function startAnimating(fps) {
    fpsInterval = 1000 / fps;
    then = Date.now();
    startTime = then;
    console.log(startTime);
    animate();
}

function animate() {

    // stop
    if (stop) {
        return;
    }

    // request another frame
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // calc elapsed time since last loop
    now = Date.now();
    elapsed = now - then;

    // if enough time has elapsed, draw the next frame
    if (elapsed > fpsInterval) {
        then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);

        // draw stuff here
        draw();

        // Statistics
        var sinceStart = now - startTime;
        var currentFps = Math.round(1000 / (sinceStart / ++frameCount) * 100) / 100;
        $results.text("FPS: " + Math.round(currentFps));

    }
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  drawBackground();
}

// Draw grid background
function drawBackground() {
  context.strokeStyle = '#e6ebf4';
  context.lineWidth = 1;

  var size = 50;
  for(var i=0; i < width + size; i+=size) {
    context.moveTo(i,0);
    context.lineTo(i,height);
    context.stroke();
  }
  for(var j=0; j < height + size; j+=size) {
     context.moveTo(0,j);
     context.lineTo(width,j);
     context.stroke();
  }
}

// resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

function resizeCanvas() {
  width = $canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  height = $canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
resizeCanvas();
```

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gf7kt8k8/

Comment: @Azamantes I mainly have jQuery for other things but figured no harm in using it here as well. This isn't the entire project nor the final scope of it.

Comment: I wasn't able to fix it, but I identified, it's the `canvas.stroke()` functions. You can make that better, if you remove them from the loop-blocks until the for loops (so one for both). However, it doesn't fix it. Im gonna try to find out more about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is, you are not clearing your paths. Use

```
context.beginPath();
```

at the begin of `draw()`.
This question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558895/html5-canvas-slows-down-with-each-stroke-and-clear#9559703)

Comment: You might want `beginPath` closer to the path commands (in drawBackground) rather than in `draw` -- not for performance reasons but just to keep "like animals" together. And speaking of paths ... you can speed up further by calling `beginPath` once just before the `i` and `j` loops and then stroke all the lines at the same time with one `stroke` after the loops. No need to stroke after every `moveTo + lineTo`.